# Netlogo - random choice

Tags: random, netlogo, agent

I am new to programming and I would really appreciate the help.
In this model, I want to create a company that can randomly choose btw 2 choices if a certain condition is met. What would be the best way to do it?
I tried this but it is not working.

```
    if profit < 0 [
set color red
let choice random 2 (
  choice = 0 [ move-to min-one-of patches [costs]] 
  choice = 1 [ set price (price + 1) ])
]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an `IFELSE` statement. Like `IF`, `IFELSE` evaluates a test, an expression that should produce either TRUE or FALSE. `IF` runs the code block when the test produces TRUE. IFELSE has two code blocks. The first will run when the test is TRUE, the second will run when the test is FALSE.

You could also use two IF statements, if you wanted to.

#### TWO IFs (Sequential IFs)

```
let choice random 2
if (choice = 0) [ action-1 ]
if (choice = 1) [ action-2 ]
```

#### IFELSE

```
let choice random 2
ifelse (choice = 0)
[ action-1 ]
[ action-2 ]
```

Note that here we only need one test: (choice = 0), because there are only two options. If choice is not 0, then it must be 1.

#### IFELSE (more than two options)

If there were more than two options, then we can use another form of ifelse that lets us use multiple tests. This form must be entirely wrapped in ( and )

```
let choice random 4
( ifelse
 ( choice = 1 ) [ action-1 ]
 ( choice = 2 ) [ action-2 ]
 ( choice = 3 ) [ action-3 ]
                [ action-4 ] ;; default
)
```